# Underlying transport used by Hazelcast?

Tags: hazelcast

Hazelcast is clearly inspired by Coherence which uses UDP monocast for inter-node communications.

Excluding the discovering phase, I see (with `lsof`) only TCP sockets connecting my cluster members.

Is that right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes that is right. Hazelcast uses a peer-to-peer clustering network, where every node speaks to every other node. Also clients are connected to each and every node, but not to other clients though.

A few things are described in the first sections of the documentation: http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.8.2/manual/html-single/index.html#hazelcast-overview